# Problems with Python's Numpy array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, dimension

I am struggling with a problem that I just can't get to work! I am currently working with Tensorflow and worked through the [basic tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/basic_classification).

As you can see in the tutorial, the neural-network-model expects a train_images Numpy array of shape `(60000, 28, 28)` as there are 60,000 images of size 28x28 in the training set of the tutorial. I am reading in the Flavia-dataset, which is a set of pictures of leaves. The traning set consists of 1588 pictures which have 300x300px resolution. Here's my code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathname_data):
for name in files:
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(os.path.join(root,name), color_mode="grayscale",target_size=(300,300))      #get image in 300x300 grayscale
    array = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)                                                                 #convert to numpy array
    array = array.squeeze(axis=2)                                                                                       #convert to 300x300 2d array
    array = array / 255.0                                                                                               #preprocess data
    pathSegments = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root,name)).split(os.sep)                                              #split path
    if pathSegments[len(pathSegments)-3] == "Train":                                                                    #assign to training- or testSet
        #TODO: how to store the 2x2 arrays ?? 
        #store in training set 
    elif pathSegments[len(pathSegments)-3] == "Test":
        #store in test set
```

My question is now, how do I store "array" so that I end up with a `(1588, 300, 300)`-shaped Numpy array that I can feed to my model? I already tried to experiment with `reshape`, append and transpose, but as of yet to no avail :( Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that every 'array' you generate from a file is a `(300, 300)` shape

You can either pregenerate the array and use a counter

```
all_img = np.empty((1588, 300, 300))
count = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathname_data):
    for name in files:
        ...
        all_img[count] = array.copy()
        count += 1
        ...
```

or you could append all the images to a list and change it into an array later

```
all_img = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pathname_data):
    for name in files:
        ...
        all_img.append(array)
        ...
all_img = np.array(all_img)
```

Both this method will give you a `(1588, 300, 300)` array, I've no experience with Tensorflow, but this is the shape you required.

Comment: Perfect! I knew it had to be simple, but I just couldn't to it last night... Thank you very much, very appreciate it!